# uploadify and absolute filepaths?

Tags: jquery, uploadify

can anyone with experience of the plugin see anything I'm doing wrong?

```
var SITE_ROOT = 'http://localhost/hf_latest_desktop/';

    $("#uploadify").uploadify({
        'uploader'       : SITE_ROOT+'st_wd_assets/js/uploadify/scripts/uploadify.swf',
        'script'         : SITE_ROOT+'st_wd_assets/js/uploadify/scripts/uploadify.php',
        'cancelImg'      : SITE_ROOT+'st_wd_assets/js/uploadify/cancel.png',
        'folder'         : SITE_ROOT+'res/img/temp',
        'auto'           : true,
        'multi'          : false,
        'buttonImg'      : SITE_ROOT+'st_wd_assets/img/uploadify-button.png'
    });
```

it loads in the swf fine (can see it in firebug), however the upload button does not show and there is no functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok after a whole day of trying to get this to work, i've abandoned uploadify and am now using [plupload](http://www.plupload.com/) which seems much better.